# Unable to update the snapshot view in clearcase on linux

Tags: clearcase

I am trying to create a new snapshot view on my machine and i am using the following procedure:

creating the view using

```
ct mkview -snapshot -tag testview -vws /home/store/testview.vws /home/view/testview
```

here the view gets created but fails to register
which i register using the `ct update on this /home/view/testview` location

tried to change the configspec using

```
ct edcs &
```

but got error "cleartool: Error: Cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object."

explicitly modifying the config_spec using vi editor, and the updating the view ends up creating a log...but no files are copied :(

Can someone please direct me as to where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is your error message on the snapshot view creation?

Something like:

```
cleartool: Warning: Unable to register new snapshot view: not a ClearCase object
snapshot view may not be recognized by some commands.
Created snapshot view directory "yourServer".
Server view_server (pid=2842) on "/home/store/testview.vws" died on startup; marking it as "down".
```

?

Any "`Unable to register new snapshot view`" message will mean that you are ot able to edit your config spec (so `ct edcs` will fail)

Try to specificy all the argument for your storage path:

```
ct mkview -snapshot -tag testview \
  -vws /home/store/testview.vws \
  -host yourServerName \
  -hpath /home/store/testview.vws \
  -gpath /home/store/testview.vws \
  /home/view/testview
```

(is your view server on the same server than your view?)

Comment: yes i get the same error message. But i tried creating the view on a different machine with the same environment and it didnt give me any error for registering.

Why do i get the error while registering the view?

and yes, my view server is on the same server as that of my view

Comment: @crystal: It usually is some kind of right issue. Is your '`id -a`' identical on both machines? Is the '`cleartool -ver`' the same on both machine? What does '`cleartool lsview -l -full -pr -cview`' returns on the second machine (the one where you did succeed creating the view) when you execute that command within the view?